# Is there no way to change startup file from index.html to something else in samsungsmart TV?

Tags: samsung-smart-tv

Is there no way to change startup file from index.html to something else in samsungsmart TV? I fno, how do I manage two different index.html files on root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think path is hard coded in SmartHub.

Nothing stops you from from using `window.location` inside **index.html** file to redirect to any file you like.

Comment: Yes that is true. But when I try that, somehow the main.js(which is different for two different pages) have some referencing problem. The appropriate functions are not getting executed.

Comment: you can name files anyway you like, no need to name them _main.js_ for both pages. just add `alert()` at beginnig of files and make sure they are loaded by TV.

Comment: Thanks  Ivan Solntsev

Comment: Hi Ivan,
When I am trying to run my application on Samsung's RTS, there is no display of my Application. Console gives an error saying-
WebKit Alert() : [Preload] Not installed Sync plus..
Any Idea?

Comment: Is your code works in emulator? I don't know what restrictions RTS devices have. You have to experiment for yourself. Try to replace redirecing _index.html_ with one of your html files and make sure it lauches.

Comment: I tried replacing some javascript files and it worked. Maybe there was some javascript code that was conflicting or giving error. 
Currently I have itegrated AdHub into my APP and on PreRoll add, the remote control events for my video ceased to work. The console says -"body is not activated currently... skip! : A". Your take on this please...

Comment: Sorry, never worked with AdHub, can't help here.

Comment: Hi Ivan,

Could you please tell me the scenario when I want my package to be deployed on multiple TV size(Samsung Smart TV). My application has tiles, and I wish to increase or decrease the number of tiles displayed in one line. Do I need to create multiple packages of varying tile count in one row for different TV sizes viz; 32 inch, 40 inch, 46 inch, 64 inch, etc.  Or, is there some better alternative. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Comments are not supposed for questions, ask new question.